# Html special characters and Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, html, encoding, special-characters

I'm using javascript and ajax framework into client side and Java glassfish into server side.

I'm trying to send a mail with this text:

```
"àèìòù !"£$%&/()=?^"
```

but when I read my post request (into java server side) I have this result:

```
"Ã Ã¨Ã¬Ã²Ã¹ !"Â£$%&/()=?^"
```

I need to convert all html special characters into respective html code, for example:

```
& -> &amp;
à -> &agrave;
```

How can I do? Thare are some javascript libraries that performs this operation?

Comment: You don't need to convert special characters. You do need to fix your encoding mismatch issues.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to one of the most stupid decisions ever. The servlet spec defines that the default encoding should be ISO-8859-1 (instead of UTF-8).

So, in order for your java application to read those characters properly after a POST, you need to set up a Servlet Filter that forcers the charset to be UTF-8. This happens because most (if not all) browsers use UTF-8 as the default charset **and** don't set the Accept-Charset header.

This is such a common thing, that tomcat bundles one of these filters([How do I change how POST parameters are interpreted?](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q3)). If you're planning to deploy to different servlet containers, I suggest you to write your own filter (just copy paste the one from tomcat).

Comment: I've tried to set CharserFilter class into my web.xml page and I've added meta tag <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">. But still not working. Can you suggest me a tutorial? I'm using glassfish...

Comment: First, check that the filter declaration and mapping is at the top of your web.xml. Otherwise, I don't know a charset/encoding tutorial for glassfish. I would suggest you to google [glassfish charset encoding filter](https://www.google.com/search?q=glassfish+charset+encoding+filter). Also, I would appreciate if you could update your question when you find the answer. I HATE THIS PROBLEM!! :'(.

Answer (score -1):

Yes! there is methods available for this, one example would to be the replace(); method.
more information [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)